# ReactJS VSCode: Cannot find name 'cy' in Cypress integration testing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, npm, cypress

I have a ReactJS Typescript project with NPM and VSCode.

I am getting the following syntax error in VSCode, even though all my Cypress tests run correctly.

```
Error: Cannot find name 'cy'
```

How can I fix?

[image]

I tried the following solution and still receiving syntax errors,

```
npm install eslint-plugin-cypress --save-dev

"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": [
    "plugin:cypress/recommended"
  ]
},
```

**Update Answer:**

Found Official solution from Cypress Documentation, posted in my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/77476529/15435022

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Official Cypress Documentation:**

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support

For Typescript configuration, Add this to tsconfig.json inside your cypress root folder:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
    "types": ["cypress", "node"]
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If using `// @ts-check` on a Javascript project, you can specify type libraries in **jsconfig.json**

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "types": [
      "cypress", 
    ]
  }
}
```

Ref: [JS Projects Utilizing TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro-to-js-ts.html)

Comment: hi, if you change your answer, to add in my json from cypress docs https://stackoverflow.com/a/77476529/15435022, I can send points, I will delete my answer, if so

Answer (score 4):

You can use a triple-slash directive in individual files (only valid at the top of the spec file)

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />
```

This is used to declare a dependency on a package, in this case the Cypress package.

Comment: I also wrote official documentation from Cypress, this works too , https://stackoverflow.com/a/77476529/15435022